# Incorrect residuals when coupling distributed and serial components

Tags: python, mpi, openmdao

I've noticed that there is a slight dependency of the residual norm in the nonlinear solver with respect to the number processors used when coupling a distributed (parallel) to a non-distributed (serial) component. I have attached an example script below.

```
'''
Simple example coupling a serial and distributed ImplicitComponent
'''

import numpy as np

import openmdao.api as om
from mpi4py import MPI
from openmdao.utils.array_utils import evenly_distrib_idxs

rank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.rank

size = 3
A = np.array([[1.0, 8.0, 0.0], [-1.0, 10.0, 2.0], [3.0, 100.5, 1.0]])

'''
This component solves the following quadratic equation in parallel:
    a_i0 * y_i^2 + a_i1 * y_i + a_i2 = x_i
    for i = {0,1,2}
where the coefficients are the components of the matrix A
'''
class DistribQuadtric(om.ImplicitComponent):
    def initialize(self):
        self.options['distributed'] = True
        self.options.declare('size', types=int, default=1,
            desc="Size of input and output vectors.")

    def setup(self):
        comm = self.comm
        rank = comm.rank

        size_total = self.options['size']

        # Distribute x and y vectors across each processor as evenly as possible
        sizes, offsets = evenly_distrib_idxs(comm.size, size_total)
        start = offsets[rank]
        end = start + sizes[rank]
        self.size_local = size_local = sizes[rank]

        # Get the local slice of A that this processor will be working with
        self.A_local = A[start:end,:]

        self.add_input('x', np.ones(size_local, float),
                       src_indices=np.arange(start, end, dtype=int))

        self.add_output('y', np.ones(size_local, float))

    def apply_nonlinear(self, inputs, outputs, residuals):
        x = inputs['x']
        y = outputs['y']
        r = residuals['y']
        for i in range(self.size_local):
            r[i] = self.A_local[i, 0] * y[i]**2 + self.A_local[i, 1] * y[i] \
            + self.A_local[i, 2] - x[i]

    def solve_nonlinear(self, inputs, outputs):
        x = inputs['x']
        y = outputs['y']
        for i in range(self.size_local):
            a = self.A_local[i, 0]
            b = self.A_local[i, 1]
            c = self.A_local[i, 2] - x[i]
            y[i] = (-b + np.sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c))/(2*a)

'''
This component solves the following linear equation in serial:
    Ax = y
'''
class SerialLinear(om.ImplicitComponent):
    def initialize(self):

        self.options.declare('size', types=int, default=1,
                             desc="Size of input and output vectors.")

    def setup(self):
        size = self.options['size']

        self.add_input('y', np.ones(size, float))

        self.add_output('x', np.ones(size, float))

        self.A = A

    def apply_nonlinear(self, inputs, outputs, residuals):
        y = inputs['y']
        x = outputs['x']
        r = residuals['x']
        r = y - A.dot(x)

    def solve_nonlinear(self, inputs, outputs):
        y = inputs['y']
        x = outputs['x']
        x[:] = np.linalg.inv(A).dot(y)

# Create a couple problem between the linear and quadratic components
prob = om.Problem()
top_group = prob.model
top_group.add_subsystem("distributed_quad", DistribQuadtric(size=size))
top_group.add_subsystem("serial_linear", SerialLinear(size=size))

# Connect variables between components
top_group.connect('serial_linear.x', 'distributed_quad.x')
top_group.connect('distributed_quad.y', 'serial_linear.y')

# Need a nonlinear solver since the model is coupled
top_group.nonlinear_solver = om.NonlinearBlockGS(iprint=2, maxiter=20)

# Setup problem
prob.setup()

# Solver problem
prob.run_model()

# Print out solution
if prob.comm.rank == 0:
    print('x', prob['serial_linear.x'])
    print('y', prob['serial_linear.y'])
```

When running this code on 1 processor the printout looks like:

```
NL: NLBGS 0 ; 2.35754338 1
NL: NLBGS 1 ; 0.256315721 0.108721529
NL: NLBGS 2 ; 0.036527896 0.0154940504
NL: NLBGS 3 ; 0.00641965062 0.00272302545
NL: NLBGS 4 ; 0.0011292331 0.000478987198
NL: NLBGS 5 ; 0.000198654857 8.42635002e-05
NL: NLBGS 6 ; 3.49479079e-05 1.48238663e-05
NL: NLBGS 7 ; 6.14814792e-06 2.60786205e-06
NL: NLBGS 8 ; 1.08160237e-06 4.58783657e-07
NL: NLBGS 9 ; 1.90279057e-07 8.0710734e-08
NL: NLBGS 10 ; 3.34745201e-08 1.41988989e-08
NL: NLBGS 11 ; 5.8889481e-09 2.49791717e-09
NL: NLBGS 12 ; 1.03600386e-09 4.3944212e-10
NL: NLBGS 13 ; 1.8225669e-10 7.7307884e-11
NL: NLBGS Converged
('x', array([-0.01251987,  0.00136932, -0.11111688]))
('y', array([-0.00156529, -0.19602066, -0.01105954]))
```

But when running on 3 processors the printout is:

```
NL: NLBGS 0 ; 5.66931072 1
NL: NLBGS 1 ; 0.6855401 0.120921243
NL: NLBGS 2 ; 0.0993351375 0.0175215546
NL: NLBGS 3 ; 0.0174731006 0.00308205026
NL: NLBGS 4 ; 0.00307353315 0.000542135243
NL: NLBGS 5 ; 0.00054069662 9.537255e-05
NL: NLBGS 6 ; 9.51208366e-05 1.67782013e-05
NL: NLBGS 7 ; 1.67339624e-05 2.95167495e-06
NL: NLBGS 8 ; 2.94389363e-06 5.19268351e-07
NL: NLBGS 9 ; 5.17899477e-07 9.1351401e-08
NL: NLBGS 10 ; 9.11105862e-08 1.60708401e-08
NL: NLBGS 11 ; 1.60284752e-08 2.82723526e-09
NL: NLBGS 12 ; 2.81978416e-09 4.97376895e-10
NL: NLBGS 13 ; 4.96064272e-10 8.74999266e-11
NL: NLBGS Converged
('x', array([-0.01251987,  0.00136932, -0.11111688]))
('y', array([-0.00156529, -0.19602066, -0.01105954]))
```

While the resulting solution to the coupled problem is the same, the residual norm used in the nonlinear solves grows as the number of processors is increased. This does not happen when coupling distributed components to distributed components or non-distributed components to non-distributed components, only when mixing them.

I believe that the cause of this discrepancy is in the underlying petsc_vector class used for parallel problems and defined in the OpenMDAO source code. Specifically, the norm definition for this class, shown below:

```
    def get_norm(self):
        """
        Return the norm of this vector.

        Returns
        -------
        float
            norm of this vector.
        """
        return self._system.comm.allreduce(np.linalg.norm(self._data))
```

This method uses an allreduce to accumulate the components of the vector over all processors into the norm. While this will give the correct result for any vector defined for distributed components (since the components of the vector are broken up across all processors), vectors for serial components contain the same copy of the vector on each processor and hence get counted multiple times in the norm depending on how many processors are used.

While the effect of this is minor in the example I showed, it grows for more complex models that may run on large numbers of processors. This can cause problems for convergence, parallel scalibilty studies, and solve tolerances. Is there a way to avoid this problem in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the report. This was definitely a bug, and is currently fixed on the latest version (0d50e7e2c26140b603460f2324e3d1d95513264a) in the OpenMDAO repo.

The latest release version (2.8) also includes this fix.